# How to properly stash my local changes permanently?

Tags: git, github

I've forked a public github project, then created a local repository, now I have to do some changes just for me that I don't want to override in the original project so I stash them. I then proceed to do the code changes I have in mind for the project and push them them remotely, then I fetch the upstream and do a pull request on the original project for my changes. Now, since I fetched the upstream, when I synchronize my local project with the remote fork my stashed changes will become the "original" again, and I have to drop my stash and do a fresh stash again. What is the proper way of doing my thought?

Comment: Just create a new branch and commit your changes. When you think it's time to publish these changes, you can apply these commits to another branch.

Comment: Yup. This is carrying a patch, it's what configuring pull.rebase or branch.mystuff.rebase  true is for.

Comment: The way I've done this in the past is to branch, commit, and later cherry pick a copy as needed.